# How to update my ssh known hosts list?

Tags: ssh, zsh, autocomplete

I changed my `/etc/hosts`, added something like this:

```
10.188.x.x   client-1
10.188.y.y   client-2
```

I used that setting for a while (`ssh client-1`), then I changed the file a second time to this:

```
10.188.x.x   cluster-0_1
10.188.y.y   cluster-0_2
```

Now if I type `ssh c<TAB>`, I expect it to be like this:

```
 ➜  ssh c
cluster-0_1  cluster-0_2
```

Instead it shows this:

```
 ➜  ssh c
client-1 client-2 cluster-0_1  cluster-0_2
```

The auto-complete still showed the options of `client-1` and `client-2`, *together with* `cluster-0_*` options. So I cleaned `.zsh_history` file, also updated `~/.ssh/kown_hosts` file by removing lines referring to the previous names (`client-*`), also restarted the `sshd` service, and even rebooted my computer, which still wouldn't work.

Also, I checked my `/etc/ssh/` directory, there wasn't one `ssh_know_hosts` file.

Maybe just headed to the wrong direction. So how can I fix this? Which file or which specific kind of files should go check? And is there a more proper way of changing my known hosts' names? Thanks a lot!

ps. By the way, the shell is `zsh` and I use `oh-my-zsh` (I wonder it might be top suspicious since offers the autocomplete part).

Comment: What do `zstyle | grep host`, `getent hosts`, `typeset  -pm '*host*'` output? Do you have anything in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`? Anything about those hosts in `~/.ssh/config` or any file included within?

Comment: You could try: start a new fresh `zsh`, run `functions -t _ssh_hosts` and `ssh c<Tab>` and check in that trace output where those `client-1`... come from.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The `typeset` shows the `clients` are actually kept in `_cache_hosts`.

Comment: typeset -a khosts=( cluster-0_1 cluster-0_2 ) typeset -a _cache_hosts=( localhost client-1 client-2 cluster-0_1 cluster-0_2 )

Comment: And the problem didn't exist very long. After a little while, it automatically solved by itself.